# Is there a way to adjust the color of a texture paint I have painted onto the model?

Tags: texture-painting, texture-baking

I have just finished texture painting my model on a base model texture. I now want to do a few alternative colours but I don't want to have to hand texture paint each new coloured model as the textures won't be consistent across each model, is their a way to change the colours of an already painted texture? or a way to bake the paints onto a different coloured model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a lot inside your shader node tree with the Color Mix nodes and other things - here I added a few procedural textures on top of the image texture I used on all of the parts using Box Mapping with Vertex Color multiplied - you can see I did some color manipulation there too.[image]